# Getting error when building in .xcodeproj - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I installed the braintree pod a long time ago in my .workspace project and tried to build my app in the .xcodeproj but am getting this error

ld: library not found for -lPayPalMobile
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Afterwards, the .workspace failed for the same reason. I have never had any problems building the app in the .workspace before this. I searched around for the solution, but nothing has worked so far.

I am not actually using braintree in my project and don't mind removing the framework altogether.

**edit** I tried updating the pod and got this message

> [Debug]`target overrides the`FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`build setting
>   defined in`Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This
>   can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

**edit 2** I deleted the braintree pod and its working fine in the .workspace file, but now the .xcodeproj has this error

> ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I searched the project and couldn't find there AFNetworking was (but in my command line it says that pod AFNetworking is being used)

Answer (score 0):

A few things. One - Make sure you're only using one .xcworkspace at a time. Also, did you open .xcworkspace or .xcodeproj? Are you trying to build custom configurations? The only other thing I can think of is your schema containing spaces.

Comment: I tried building it in the .xcodeproj which caused the error and then I tried in the .xcworkspace, which now also has the error. I am not trying to build custom configurations. Could you tell me more about the schema?

Comment: You can't have any spaces in your schema or else you will get the error message you received.